# LWJGL - White border on my 3D quads when they are like 10f away from camera pos

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I get weird white borders on my 3D quads when they are a little ways away from the camera position and when they are close the borders disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using power-of-two textures as non-power-of-two textures may cause problems with texturing.

Try replacing this fragment:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
        GL11.GL_NEAREST);
```

with this:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
        GL11.GL_LINEAR);
```

You can also try replacing this:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
```

with this:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I think the problem may be in in texture coordinates - how do you initialize them and do you change them while program is running? Texture coordinates may have values only from 0 to 1 and in most cases these are not changing while program is running.

Comment: I am using a 384X256 and I tried what you said it didn't help. it made the quality look bad.. Should I replace the texture size?

Comment: I tried a 512X256 texture and it didnt help.. But now the lines are finer they are less blury

Comment: I think that the texture size is causing this problem - it is always better to use power of two textures even if your texture does not fill the whole image and then use correct texture coordinates.

Comment: Could it be the mipmap? is there a way to remove the mipmap because when i try to remove the line with the mipmap the textures dont work...

Comment: Textures without mipmaps cannot work when you have GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR in code, but will work after replacing GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR with GL11.GL_LINEAR

Comment: I don't know where may be the bug as code you shown above is correct, but I suspect that the problem may be in rendering code. Can you show this part or the whole code and resources (if this in not problem, naturally)?